# c# find and replace an unknown word between markers/know words

Tags: c#, regex

Im trying to make a program that replace a word in a file but i dont know how to replace when the word is now a unknown word
this is my code for replace when the file is unmodified, but when the user change the word/nickname and want to change it again, i need to know that word/nickname between 2 words

```
string path2 = filePath + "\\test\\versions\\"+comboBox1.Text+"\\";
            string text = File.ReadAllText(path2+comboBox1.Text+".json");
            text = text.Replace("${auth_player_name}", textBox1.Text);
            File.WriteAllText(path2+comboBox1.Text+".json", text);
```

this is the 2 words between the word that i need to replace

```
--username ${auth_player_name} --version
```

now im trying to change the unknown word to ${auth_player_name} so the user can change it again, this need to be that word because my program can edit other files that are similar but with other name

i tried this but dont work

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "--username \".*\" --ver", "-username \"${auth_player_name}\" --ver");
```

This is all the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ChangeName
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(filePath+"\\.minecraft\\versions");
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (FileInfo folder in Files)
                comboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(folder.Name));
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string path2 = filePath + "\\.minecraft\\versions\\"+comboBox1.Text+"\\";
            string text = File.ReadAllText(path2+comboBox1.Text+".json");
            text = text.Replace("${auth_player_name}", textBox1.Text);
            File.WriteAllText(path2+comboBox1.Text+".json", text);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide example data of what may be in between those two words?

Comment: Really, can you say, I have this and I want it to look like that?

Comment: literally though this is what you'd use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: An example of input/output would be helpful. You are using the word "word" a lot and it's hard to see what you mean precisely.

Comment: @Rutix example for that word is a nickname/username/displayname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Regex.Replace Example

```
string path2 = filePath + "\\test\\versions\\"+comboBox1.Text+"\\";
string text = File.ReadAllText(path2+comboBox1.Text+".json");
//Changed to Regex
Regex reg = new Regex("--username ([^-]+)--version");
//using regex.replace function
text = reg.Replace(text, "--username " + textBox1.Text + " --version");
//end edit
File.WriteAllText(path2+comboBox1.Text+".json", text);
```

**[Documentation for Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

Updated to set text variable equal to the replacement.

Comment: tried that but don't work the file keep intact, when i select in the program the version/comboBox and put a nickname/textbox and click the button the file keep intact without changes

Comment: @rakion99 : Did you debug? Where does it go wrong? Does it do the replacement correctly? You should really give more information then just say "tried that but doesn't work"

Comment: @abc123 **thanks you very much now works perfect** and sorry for no give you more information im new to asking xD

Comment: @rakion99 not a problem